# Mixed Distribution Question

Tags: self-study, random-variable, joint-distribution

Let

$$f\left(x,y\right)= \begin{cases} \frac{1}{3}, & x = 1, \, 0 \le y \le 1 \\ \frac{1}{6}, & x = 2, \, 0 \le y \le 2 \\ \frac{1}{9}, & x = 3, \, 0 \le y \le 3 \end{cases}$$

I want to find

$\mathbb{P}(X >1 ,Y < 1),\mathbb{P}(X > 2,Y < 2),\mathbb{P}(X > 2,Y < 3)$

Answer:-
X is having discrete distribution and Y is having Continuous distribution.So how to answer this question? Your guidance is needed.If anyone answer this question correctly, it is very good.

Comment: $P(X > 1,Y < 1) = P(X=2,Y<1) + P(X=3,Y <1)$. Compute each of the summands by integrating the joint density f(x,y) for the corresponding values of x over the desired region of Y (in this case $0 \le y \le 1$).  Use a similar approach for the other probabilities you wish to compute.

Comment: @Mark L.Stone So answer to(1) is $\frac{5}{18}$and answers to (2) and (3) are $\frac16 $ and $\frac19$ respectively. are these answers correct?

Comment: @Mark $f$ is not a joint density, because it's singular in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Although that might seem to be a quibble, it likely gets to the heart of the difficulty expressed in the question. If, instead, you were to direct the OP to *condition* on $X$ (which is what you seem to be advising), then all would be well, because this distribution *does* have a conditional density for all values of $X$ having positive probability.

Comment: @whuber yes you are correct. I was being lazy in not explicitly mentioning conditioning on X and in referring to joint rather than conditional density.

Comment: @Dhamnekar I agree with the results in your comment for one of the three probabilities. I leave it for you to determine which are correct/wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem describes a random variable $(X,Y)$ that does not have a density function.  However, *conditional on the value of $X$*, $Y$ will have a density function (provided $X$ is one of $1,2,3$) as specified in the question.

We may visualize this as a density that is comprised of three parts: one part for $X=1$, another for $X=2$, and a third for $X=3$.  As always, the total area under the graph of the density function must be $1$.  Here is a picture showing all three parts with the areas beneath them filled in:

[image: Figure 1]

The nonzero area of each region is a rectangle.  The rectangles have areas $1/3\times 1=1/3$, $1/6\times 2=1/3$, and $1/9 \times 3=1/3$ for a total of $1$, as expected.

We may depict any event by showing which combinations of $X$ and $Y$ belong to it.  For example, the event abbreviated by "$X\gt 1, Y \lt 1$" consists of all points *on any of the three y-axes* for which $x\gt 1$ *and* $y \lt 1$.  Evidently that rules out anything where $x=1$ as well as any portion where $y\ge 1$.  To show this, the next figure blots out the entire plot for $x=1$ and it shades (in red) the portions of the other two plots for which $y \lt 1$.

[image: Figure 2]

**The desired probability is the sum of all red areas that have not been shaded out.**  There are two such red areas: one for $x=2$, a rectangle of base $1$ and height $1/6$; and one for $x=3$, a rectangle of base $1$ and height $1/9$.  The sum of their areas

$$1 \times 1/6 + 1 \times 1/9 = 5/18$$

is the probability of this event.

The other questions may be solved in the same way.

---

**The correctness of this visualization is assured by the axioms of probability.**  Any event $E\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ can be partitioned into four non-overlapping events $E_1 = \{(x,y)\,|\, x=1\}$, $E_2 = \{(x,y)\,|\, x=2\}$, $E_3 = \{(x,y)\,|\, x=3\}$, and $E_0=\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus (E_1 \cup E_2 \cup E_3)$ (which consists of everything else).  We worked out that $\Pr(E_1)=\Pr(E_2)=\Pr(E_3)=1/3$, implying (by the law of total probability) that $\Pr(E_0) = 1-(1/3+1/3+1/3)=0$.  That permits us to ignore $E_0$ altogether.  Consequently, the figures represent the conclusion that for all events $E$,

$$\Pr(E) = \Pr(E_1) + \Pr(E_2) + \Pr(E_3).$$

Moreover, for $i=1,2,3$, the definition of conditional probability tells us

$$\Pr(E_i) = \Pr(E_i\,|\, X=i)\,\Pr(X=i).$$

The function $f$ is none other than a specification of the *densities* for each of those conditional probabilities, each multiplied by $\Pr(X_i)$.  Consequently,

$$\Pr(E) = \sum_{i=1}^3 \int_{E\cap \{x=i\}} f(i,y) dy.$$

The figures depict those three integrals.

Comment: Your answer is correct and removed ambiguity about the question out of my mind. Your graphs are self-explanatory.